# Kurento Video Streaming

Tags: java, video-streaming, progressive-download, kurento

I want to access the video stream being recorded by Kurento in Real-Time.

In the default implementation, I can only get hold of the video once the call is completed, but how can I access the file as it is being created?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to connect a `PlayerEndpoint` or a media player to watch the recording in real time, if the recorded file is in VP8 format. On the other hand, if you are recording in .mp4 format, there is no way to do that because .mp4 stores certain information when the recording process ends. This is not particular to Kurento, but to .mp4